# Can German Potato Balls be frozen?

Tags: freezing, potatoes, german-cuisine

Can they be frozen, before being cooked, for a week? I'm making sauerbrauten & potato balls for 25 people, and thought if I could make them a week earlier and just cook them that day, it would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can freeze them: I have done it before, and it works just fine.

They key (in my experience, that is) is to freeze the balls quickly if uncooked, and put them into the boiling water still frozen when you actually do the cooking.

I have also been freezing cooked potato balls, and that works just fine as well -> In that case, warm them up in hot, but not boiling, water.

A note due to the comment below: The recipe I use calls for half cooked, and half raw potatoes, with the raw half being pressed almost totally try of water; and they DO fall apart if I do not take that part seriously. So, except for potato-flour added again, there is not that much raw potato starch left when I freeze them.

Comment: I've actually never tried, but always heard (and believed) that you shouldn't freeze raw potatoes, since the freezing process would convert some of the potato starch into sugar?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added a note, because this was never really a problem for me when it comes to potato-balls, but it MAY be one depending on the recipe.. I added a notice above to reflect on the starch/sugar thing :).

Comment: What a great first post. Welcome to Seasoned Advice, Layna!

Comment: Thank you :).I have already learned quiet a bit just from reading here! Great site with great people :).

Answer (score 0):

Probably. Here's a recipe that that's similar: [Au Gratin Potato balls](http://www.food.com/recipe/awesome-augratin-potato-balls-431395). I'd recommend that you freeze them on sheets, and then once frozen, pack in Ziploc bags. As long as your time frame is so short (anything less than a month), that should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

When I cook potato dumplings, I use cooked mashed potatoes, so cooking raw potatoes is not an issue. Also I normally freeze cooked potato dumplings on a tray in the freezer when they first rise to top of pan. Next I will try freezing uncooked potato dumplings--hoping they will rise to top as normal.